# WARNING: under normal conditions, _fillInQueueWithExtraSpace:ignoreExistingItems: should not be re-entered

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, avfoundation

This is my class that managed my video:

```
#import "video.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface video()
{
    MPMoviePlayerController* videoView;
}
@end

@implementation video

static video *sharedSingleton = nil;

+ (video *)sharedSingleton
{
    @synchronized([video class])
    {
        if (!sharedSingleton)
            sharedSingleton = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
        return sharedSingleton;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (id)init 
{
    self = [super init];

    CGRect dimVideo = CGRectMake(0, 0, 472, 400);
    NSURL* videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"videoName" withExtension: @"mp4"];

    self->videoView = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoPath];
    [self->videoView.view setFrame:dimVideo];
    [self->videoView prepareToPlay];

    return self;
}

- (void)addVideoOn:(UIView*)view{
    [view addSubview:self->videoView.view];
    [self->videoView play];
}

- (void)removeVideo{
    [self->videoView stop];
    [self->videoView.view removeFromSuperview];
}

@end
```

But sometimes I get this error when play the video:
WARNING: under normal conditions, _fillInQueueWithExtraSpace:ignoreExistingItems: should not be re-entered.

Where is the problem?
Thank you in advance

I noticed one thing:
video freezes when you pass the time between the stop and play.
I fixed the error leaving the video paused, not stopped.

Comment: it's conventional to capitalize your class names: "Video" instead of "video"

Comment: also this will crash if `self == nil` for whatever reason in `-init`

Comment: the documentation for `MPMoviePlayerController` says "player's frame must match parent's" which is not the case for your code. I would try fixing that first.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would structure your code

```
@interface Video : NSObject
@property ( nonatomic, strong, readonly ) MPMoviePlayerController * videoView ;
@end

@implementation Video
@synthesize videoView = _videoView ;

+(Video *)sharedSingleton
{
   static Video * __sharedSingleton ;
   static dispatch_once_t once ;
   dispatch_once( &once, ^{
       __sharedSingleton = [ [ [ self class ] alloc ] init ] ;
   }
   return __sharedSingleton ;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [ _videoView stop ] ;
    [ _videoView.view removeFromSuperview ] ;
}

-(void)ensureMoviePlayer
{
   if (!_videoView ) 
   { 
       NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"videoName" withExtension:@"mp4"];
       _videoView = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
   }
}

- (void)addVideoOn:(UIView*)view
{
   [ self ensureMoviePlayer ] ;
   self.videoView.view.frame = view.bounds ; // per documentation
   [view addSubview:self.videoView.view];
   [self.videoView play];
}

- (void)removeVideo
{
   [self.videoView stop];
   [ self.videoView.view removeFromSuperview ] ;
}

@end
```

If you're trying to play video at a certain size within a parent view, look at `AVPlayer` + `AVPlayerLayer`