# MPMoviePlayer warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, video, ios4

Sometimes when my iPad starts playing video, I get below warning
WARNING:
`under normal conditions, _fillInQueueWithExtraSpace:ignoreExistingItems: should not be re-entered.`
Anyone have any idea on why I am getting this warning?
I found questions like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263323/warning-under-normal-conditions-fillinqueuewithextraspaceignoreexistingitems) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806826/got-the-message-warning-under-normal-conditions-fillinqueuewithextraspace) but it was not useful.

Comment: no im still getting this warning : (

Comment: some1 help me with this error please :D i really can't find anywhere solution :(

Comment: for me this seems to happen only on iOS 5.x. Also when there are two or more players. As per the MPMoviePlayerController documentation only one movie player instance should be created and reused. But am having the second movie player in UIWebView which is causing this issue with the MPMoviePlayerController instance that i have created.  did anyone find solution or other reason for this....

Answer (score 0):

Please check the movie players loadState before playing the movie. Play movie only when the load is not MPMovieLoadStateUnknown. If it is then setContentUrl and call perpareToPlay.